# How to make Django modifiy JSONField value effictively

Tags: django, jsonfield

With MySQL8.0.25 as database backend, I make Django ORM to update the following JSONField value

```json
{
  "01-task1": {"data":"huge data here"}
}
```

just add a new element , `"02-testing": {}`

but I got the following sql log

```sql
(0.000) UPDATE `by_jsontree_store1` SET `store_type` = 1, `user_id` = 2, `data` = '{\"01-task1\": {\"data\": \"huge data here\"}, \"02-testing\": {}}' 

WHERE `by_jsontree_store1`.`id` = 1; args=(1, 2, '{"01-task1": {"data": "huge data here"}, "02-testing": {}}', 1)
```

It looks like Django rewrite the whole content of that JSONField.

The Django JSONField does map to MySQL JSON column type, as the following table struct shows.

[image]

Imaging if the original content is huge, like 100MB, what could happen.

Could Django update JSON field partially, just update what it need to?

Comment: You can use chained lookups for key or index based transformations on `JSONField`, but I don't think such an operation is permitted by the `update` method.

Comment: So you mean, for time being, Django can not  convert ORM JSONField updating to  to JSON_SET, JSON_REPLACE and JSON_REMOVE in MYSQL8.0 ？ So we have to write raw sql to do that?

Comment: if there's a way, maybe posting on forum.djangoproject.com can look. There are more django developers there.

Comment: Thank you, I've posted.  https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/how-to-make-django-modifiy-jsonfield-value-effictively/8937